# nf2-pdf-view - how to show scrollbars

Tags: angular, ng2-pdf-viewer

I have an Angular app with ng2-pdf-viewer version 6.4.1, but I couldn't make it show scrollbars. It can only be scrolled using the mouse wheel.
I tried applying several CSS options, but it didn't work. In the inspector it looks like this:

[image]

The component doesn't seem to have a setting for this.
How can I force the scrollbars to be shown?